# Soomla OnRestoreTransactionsFinished always received TRUE

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, soomla

I'm currently working on a mobile game using Unity3D and Soomla for the in-app purchases part. Currently I'm trying to implement the 'restore' functionality for non-consumable item (I only have 1 which is "No Ads"). In order to do this; I used "SoomlaStore.RestoreTransactions" functions and restore the item if "OnRestoreTransactionsFinished" received true.

The problem is that whenever the "OnRestoreTransactionsFinished" is called, the value it received will always be TRUE even though that device/account never purchase the item before. According to Soomla website;

> success is a boolean value that says if the restore transactions
>   operation hass succeeded or failed

Am I misunderstanding something here? Does the value will always be true even if the account never purchase the item before? Does this means I need to use something else to check whether the item should be restore and that my way of doing things now are totally wrong? Thank you.

Comment: After testing/ researching different things I've decided to change the way I do things. I've found a different function; "StoreInventory.GetItemBalance" which takes a string (itemId) and returns an int. This allows me to check if the account already purchase the item before or not and restore it if they have.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers... OnRestoreTransactionsFinished returns whether or not the transactions have been restored or not. It does not tell which products or anything.

The RestoreTransactions function call will call the OnMarketPurchased event for each item restored, so you can use that to update your app with each item that has been restored.